# Eliminating unwanted linebreaks in a CSV file

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv

I have a very large CSV file (million+ rows), on which I'd like to perform some operations. Problem is, some of the rows have some unwanted linebreaks, like this:

```
New York City; Iron Man; no superpowers;
Metropolis; Superman; superpowers;
New York City;
Spider-Man;
superpowers;
Gotham; Batman; no superpowers;
New York City; Doctor Strange; superpowers;
```

The file thus has three columns (`location`,`superhero`, `superpowers`). Since the entry for Spider-Man is faulty, as it has linebreaks between its entries, pandas falsely assumes that those are three seperate rows, wit `NaNs` in the second and third column.

My idea was to fix this during import with regex. According to [this website](https://regex101.com/r/R6steZ/1/), this regex correctly matches the desired rows, and doesn't match the faulty ones (i.e. Spider-Man).

`(.*[;].*[;].*)`

Its inverse (`(?!(.*[;].*[;].*))`, however, doesn't work, because it not only doesn't match the three faulty rows, but also the third entry of every normal row.

My other approach was to simply set the number of columns and then remove all linebreaks from the the entire file. That didn't work either, though.

```
superhero_df = pd.read_csv("superheroes.csv", sep=' *; *', skiprows=12, names=["location", "superhero", "superpower"], index_col=False, engine="python")
superhero_df = superhero_df.replace('\r\n','', regex=True)
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
New York City; Iron Man; no superpowers
Metropolis; Superman; superpowers;
New York City; Spider-Man; superpowers;
Gotham; Batman; no superpowers;
New York City; Doctor Strange; superpowers;
```

Comment: You may run something like https://ideone.com/jTP9S3 to preprocess the file, write it to another one (use `f.write(newfile)` instead of `print` commands), and then load it as usual. That means you do not have to read the whole file into memory. What you are trying is to first load the contents into dataframe, and then run `replace`, while it should be vice versa: first replace, then load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that:

```
^([^;]+);[\r\n]*([^;]+);[\r\n]*([^;]+);
```

and replace by:

```
\1;\2;\3;
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VpCwKF/1)

[run here](https://ideone.com/Z1Bv9B)

```
import re

regex = r"^([^;]+);[\r\n]*([^;]+);[\r\n]*([^;]+);"

test_str = ("New York City; Iron Man; no superpowers;\n"
    "Metropolis; Superman; superpowers;\n"
    "New York City;\n"
    "Spider-Man;\n"
    "superpowers;\n"
    "Gotham; Batman; no superpowers;\n"
    "New York City; Doctor Strange; superpowers;\n\n")

subst = "\\1;\\2;\\3;"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with my data, as the result's still the same. Printing the faulty lines with pandas outputs the following: ```'location        New York City\nsuperhero NaN\nsuperpower           None\nName: 131061, dtype: object'```

Answer (score 1):

The following regex eliminates unwanted line breaks and other white spaces after every three fields. It assumes that the fields do not have any internal semicolons:

```
print(re.sub(r'([^;]*);\s*([^;]*);\s*([^;]*);\s+', r'\1;\2;\3\n', 
      line, flags=re.M))
#New York City; Iron Man;no superpowers
#Metropolis;Superman;superpowers
#New York City;Spider-Man;superpowers
#Gotham;Batman;no superpowers
#New York City;Doctor Strange;superpowers
```

You can run it in a loop to preprocess the file before using Pandas.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, as the result's still the same. Printing the fault lines outputs: ```'location        New York City\nsuperhero NaN\nsuperpower           None\nName: 131061, dtype: object'```

Comment: I used your sample data and got the expected results. Where are the nans coming from? You should clean the CSV file _before_ loading it to pandas. There should be no nans in it.

Comment: You were right. I went through the file before loading it, but it still doesn't seem to work. That's what I did: ```tmp = ""

for line in data.splitlines():
  line = re.sub(r'([^;]*);\s*([^;]*);\s*([^;]*);\s+', r'\1;\2;\3\n', line, flags=re.M) 
  tmp += line```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd rewrite the whole data in a new text file with a simple iteration over the source text file and load the resulting file into Pandas, no `re` needed:

```
with open('source.txt') as fin, open('target.txt', 'w') as fout:
    lc = 0
    for line in fin:
        lc += line.count(';')
        if  lc < 3:
            fout.write(line[:-1])
        else:
            fout.write(line)
            lc = 0
```

Result:

```
# New York City; Iron Man; no superpowers;
# Metropolis; Superman; superpowers;
# New York City;Spider-Man;superpowers;
# Gotham; Batman; no superpowers;
# New York City; Doctor Strange; superpowers;
```

Reading into Pandas:

```
pd.read_csv('target.txt', header=None, sep=';', usecols=range(3))

#                0                1                2
# 0  New York City         Iron Man   no superpowers
# 1     Metropolis         Superman      superpowers
# 2  New York City       Spider-Man      superpowers
# 3         Gotham           Batman   no superpowers
# 4  New York City   Doctor Strange      superpowers
```

---

Note: `usecols` is only needed because of the trailing semicolon. This can be avoided by importing with

```
with open('source.txt') as fin, open('target.txt', 'w') as fout:
    lc = 0
    for line in fin:
        lc += line.count(';')
        if  lc < 3:
            fout.write(line.strip())
        else:
            fout.write(line.strip()[:-1] + '\n')
            lc = 0
```

Reading into Pandas:

```
pd.read_csv('target.txt', header=None, sep=';')

#                0                1                2
# 0  New York City         Iron Man   no superpowers
# 1     Metropolis         Superman      superpowers
# 2  New York City       Spider-Man      superpowers
# 3         Gotham           Batman   no superpowers
# 4  New York City   Doctor Strange      superpowers
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

string = """New York City; Iron Man; no superpowers;
Metropolis; Superman; superpowers;
New York City;
Spider-Man;
superpowers;
Gotham; Batman; no superpowers;
New York City; Doctor Strange; superpowers;"""

cities=[]
superheros=[]
superpowers = []

splited_list = re.split(';', string)
splited_list.pop(len(splited_list) - 1 )

i = 0

while i < len(splited_list) - 1:
    cities.append(splited_list[i])
    superheros.append(splited_list[i + 1])
    superpowers.append(splited_list[i + 2])

    i = i + 3


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "City": cities,
    "Superhero": superheros,
    "superpowers": superpowers
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach, not optimized for performance but I can do it:

```
from pprint import pprint

def main():
    count=0
    outer_list=[]
    row=[]
    with open('superheroes.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split(";"):
                if not str.isspace(word):
                    word=word.strip()
                    row.append(str(word))
                    count = count + 1
                    if count % 3 == 0:
                        outer_list.append(row)
                        row=[]
    pprint(outer_list)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

the output is a list of lists:

```
[['New York City', 'Iron Man', 'no superpowers'],
 ['Metropolis', 'Superman', 'superpowers'],
 ['New York City', 'Spider-Man', 'superpowers'],
 ['Gotham', 'Batman', 'no superpowers'],
 ['New York City', 'Doctor Strange', 'superpowers']]
```